# computer is not operational

Tags: boot-repair

I recently tried to upgrade my computer from 15.10. However, my live cd states I do not have enough drive space. After attempting several times to upgrade I have lost the ability to use my computer. It will not boot , I cannot get to the grub menu or the terminal to make changes. The only time I can use my computer is in the try ubuntu mode.  However, recently in the try ubuntu mode my system will freeze up after a minute of use. I cannot watch videos on youtube without them freezing and it is impossible to write or view emails.
Is it possible to get another cd from ubuntu that will allow me to delete unwanted files, or get me to the grub menu or the terminal when my computer will not boot. How can I get my computer back or is it too late and I will have to replace it.

Comment: If it's a hardware problem getting another CD won't fix it. Check the RAM and check the graphics card if there is one.

Comment: Thank you Karel, however I'm not that advance with computers. I don't know how to check the RAM and I definitely don't know what a graphics card is.

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory 2. https://superuser.com/questions/1057581/what-is-the-difference-between-on-board-and-discrete-graphics/1107633#1107633 By checking I mean if there are two RAM sticks remove the RAM one stick at a time, and check if the computer boots without it.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by removing not needed files. Replace `sda1` with your partition with your data (if you don't know try it as it is):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo thunar /mnt/home/
```

This will mount your hard drive and start thunar. There you should be able to delete files you don't need.

Comment: *Might* work when `/dev/sda1` is the root partition containing `/home` and when using Xubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that biillwhyte is a begginer, so I put here sda1 for simplicity, and he'll reply if it doesn't work. It probably wasn't a bright idea when I think about it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: FK-VH,
 I'm still a little confused. How can I  input the following commands ( $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo thunar /mnt/home/ ) if I cannot boot my computer, or get into the terminal mode or grub menu. Also, I would love to remove unwanted files or any files that will allow me to upgrade.

Comment: You can use terminal app on live cd

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, however something happen today that took me completely by surprise. I signed on my computer as usual and information begin downloading  Afterward, I discover I no-longer had the message I didn't have enough drive space. I begin the upgrade without checking the two boxes, one for additional updates and the other for third party downloads. I stopped the upgrade hoping I could check the boxes and continue. This was a mistake on my part because I could not restart the upgrade. I will try the two sudo commands and see what happens. Once again thanks for your support.

Comment: Guys I used the two commands, in the terminal mode. This is what came back.t

Comment: Guys I used the two commands, in the terminal mode. This is what came back.                                   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  sudo thunar /mnt/home/
sudo: thunar: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$